# Array destructuration in CoffeeScript (fetch first and last items from an Array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

This [example](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) (5th code block in the section) of the CoffeeScript documentation states that the following CoffeeScript code:

```
text = "Every literary critic believes he will
        outwit history and have the last word"

[first, ..., last] = text.split " "
```

translates into this snippet of Javascript:

```
var first, last, text, _ref;

text = "Every literary critic believes he will outwit history and have the last word";

_ref = text.split(" "), first = _ref[0], last = _ref[_ref.length - 1];
```

If you use the Coffee -> JS parser on their website, this example translates into CoffeeScript accordingly. However, I tried it on a Rails project and I'm getting a `SyntaxError: unexpected ...`. Same error if you try the example in [CoffeeLint](http://www.coffeelint.org/).

Do you have any idea why this example from the documentation doesn't work? Am I missing something?

Comment: The `...` support is only a week or two old.

Comment: Update your version of coffeescript if you want that feature

Comment: Oh, now I feel stupid for being in a hurry and making a question before even checking versions on both my gem and on the Lint website.  Anyone of you care to make a proper answer so I can validate it, or do we remove the question for being quite useless?

Comment: You could always answer it yourself, that's allowed but there might be a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Pointy and jgitter in the comments, this CoffeeScript feature is relatively new.
As of the time of writing this answer (February 17, 2014):

- The gem `coffee-script` used in Ruby on Rails is using CoffeeScript `1.6.3`.
- The website [Coffeelint](http://coffeelint.org) is compatible up to CoffeeScript `1.6`

---

[CoffeeScript Changelog](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog):

> 1.7.0 – JANUARY 28, 2014
>
> - Added **, // and %% operators and ... expansion in parameter lists
>     and destructuring expressions.